# How to show the Text box layout in MVC as text box without having drop down in the side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal

How to show the Text box layout in MVC as text box without having drop down in the side?

In the attached screen shot, we have the drop down lay out. It has to be plain text box.

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 control-label">
                            <label class="hthin">ExceriseTimes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <textarea id="ExceriseTimes" asp-for="ExceriseTimes" style="height:25px;" class="form-control" type="text"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<textarea>` form element doesn't have `type` attribute, it belongs to `<input>`. If you want a plain single-line text box, just use `<input>` tag with `type="text"` attribute:

```
<input id="ExerciseTimes" asp-for="ExerciseTimes" style="height:25px;" class="form-control" 
       type="text" />
```

However if you want fixed size `<textarea>` element without scroll bar (looks like spinner in sample image), use both CSS styling `overflow:hidden` & `resize:none`:

```
<textarea id="ExerciseTimes" asp-for="ExerciseTimes" style="height:25px;" class="form-control" 
          style="overflow:hidden;resize:none"></textarea>
```

**Note:** You can apply additional CSS class containing both styles above (e.g. `noscrollbar`) and append it like `class="form-control noscrollbar"`.